# Ubuntu 14.04 guest cannot detect second virtualbox monitor

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) VirtualBox setup on VirtualBox 4.3.30. As I understand it, this setup should permit the use of Dual Monitors by the guest OS. The host OS is Windows 7.

I have the guest additions package installed. I have tried both using and ignoring the x86 virtualisation solution. I have video memory set to 128MB (have also tried 64MB). The Number of monitors is set to 2. I have tried both with an without 3d acceleration. I have two physical monitors, if that makes a difference.

The settings on the Ubuntu Guest fail to detect a second monitor, and no second monitor is shown by VirtualBox.

How to I arrange this setup so that I can have two 'monitors' on my guest machine?

EDIT:

Bizarrely, this works for 32 bit Ubuntu on the same Host. Should this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The virtualbox additions from the apt repository are not up-to-date. By reinstalling them from the iso provided by virtualbox, this issue was resolved.